# Sizing android tabs and fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment

I am new to Android but know how to work Java so I am just needing help on some of the layout parts of my Application.

Basically I wish to have 4 tabs at the top of the application (this I have done) and when clicking on each it will display a different fragment (very new so this may not be right) which will serve a different purpose.

The first issue I am not sure how to solve is that I wish for the first three tabs (keyboard, media remote and mouse) to be larger than the settings tab (which I will change to an icon if possible). I wish for the first three to have equal width and the fourth to be a lot smaller.

Secondly how would I have different fragments appear when clicking on the corresponding tab (e.g. clicking "MEDIA REMOTE" would open mediaRemoteFragment). This application will be a client so a main part (MainActivity.java??) would be needed to run in the background and then the fragments would send messages to the main which would then send these messages to the server.

Sorry if this is a little unclear...

Here's my current code:

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

import layout.FragmentTab;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("keyboardTab").setIndicator("Keyboard", null), FragmentTab.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("mediaRemoteTab").setIndicator("Media Remote", null), FragmentTab.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("mouseTab").setIndicator("Mouse", null), FragmentTab.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("settingsTab").setIndicator("Settings", null), FragmentTab.class, null);

    }
}
```

FragmentTab.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import kaihulme.tabs.R;

public class FragmentTab extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText(this.getTag() + " Content");
        return v;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

fragment_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#eaecee">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="hello_world"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your layouts, they are rigth for me.
First you will have to create the 4 fragments. The you will need to implement the `onClik()` listenert on the tabs to follow this process: when you click a tab the actual `fragment` should disappear, so it should be removed and a new fragment should be created and inserted on the `FrameLayout`. You can use the method `replace()` for that purpose.

The fragment template that android studio autogenerate it's very useful. And here you have a lot of info to work with fragments: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html

The most important it's:
When you need to replace the fragment, remove the old fragment and create the new one with `newInstance()` method provided by android studio that you must change to match your needs.

`KeyboardFragment mFrag = KeyboardFragment.newInstace(arg1, arg2);`

You can call fragment methods saving the instance of the created fragment:

`mFrag.myMethod();`

But you mustn't call Activity methods from the fragment. To share information, notice some event, etc you must use an interface as explained in the previous article:

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    OnArticleSelectedListener mListener;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The Activity must implements that interface and then you can call interface methods to communicate your fragment with your container activity.

Hope it helps to start your work.

Comment: Thank you for the response - I shall try this out